# Can I have a ranking from my data value into a tooltip with Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, tooltip, leaflet

I am making a ***Choropleth Map*** consisting of 799 regions, colored by `score` value, so I was wondering if I could add ranking of each region dynamically into a tooltip.

For example : "This region : #1 of #799" etc...

Part of my data which are in a csv :

```
region | score
--------------
  a    |  0.5
  b    |  1.2
  c    |  3.7
  d    |  1
  e    |  2.3
```

Answer (score 0):

There is probably no out-of-the-box solution. But this is quite straight forward.

You would need to perform a "preprocessing" step in order to determine the ranking, then you could add this data into your regions popup for example.

1. Fill an array with your regions data.
2. [Sort the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) using a compare function that uses your `score`.
3. Fill the regions layer popup with the index (+1) of the region within the array, of the length of the array.